# Making alphabetical citation call-outs to a hand-built bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am new to LaTeX and am currently trying to write a master thesis. I was thinking of writing the bibliography using `\begin{thebibliography}{9}` since I will probably not use it ever again. Does `natbib` work together with the bibliography? If not, is there another way to get alphabetical labels in the square brackets?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\begin{document}

\citep{lamport94}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{Biblitest}
 Bibli Test.
 The book of biblitests.
 1nd edition.
 2016.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is self-contradictory.  If you use `thebibliography` there is no point in using a BibTeX-style such as `natbib`.  Also `natbib` heavily relies on the output generated by its BibTeX-style.  All in all, I would recommend abandoning `natbib` *and* `thebibliography` in favour of [`biblatex`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf), which is way more sophisticated and allows for much more configuration and automation.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  The code is not really relevant to your question, but please always post copyable code.  Therefore just indent lines by 4 spaces and they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/10995

Comment: Welcome to [TeX SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  In addition to Henri's comment, even if you don't use it ever again I would highly recommend using a reference manager such as BibDesk, JabRef, Zotero, Mendeley, or any other that has a BibTeX output or sync option ([this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software) is a fairly comprehensive list).   Especially because most modern managers allow you to import via the web or via DOI so you don't have to type your Bibliography yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the earlier commenters have already pointed out, if you're going to build the bibliography by hand, there is (a) no point in specifying a bibliography style (since you won't be invoking BibTeX to create the formatted bibliography) and (b) little point in general in loading the `natbib` package. I deliblerately say "little point in general", rather than "no point," for `natbib` as it *might* make sense to load the package if you want to use both `\citet` and `\citep` and wish to create authoryear-style citation call-outs.

However, since it looks like you're set to use an "alphabetical" style for the citation callouts, there's actually no reason to load `natbib` for the case at hand. Instead, you may want to structure the `\bibitem` entries as shown in the following example. Note the presence of `Jon99` in the optional argument of `\bibitem` -- that's the piece of information that will be shown in the citation callouts.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\cite{jones:99}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem[Jon99]{jones:99} Jones, Andrew, \emph{Collected Works}, 
Nowhere: NoCollege Press, 1999.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```